# Bash Script: egrep not returning results with single quote in variable

Tags: bash, scripting

I am writing a simple bash script that is doing the following:

```
cmd="egrep -i Hello /home/me/foo.txt"
if [ -n $cmd ]
then
    $cmd
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "YAY"
    else
        echo "BOO"
    fi
fi
```

This returns "YAY". However, if I add single quotes around Hello, the scripts returns "BOO"

```
cmd="egrep -i 'Hello' /home/me/foo.txt"
if [ -n $cmd ]
then
    $cmd
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "YAY"
    else
        echo "BOO"
    fi
fi
```

I have been wracking my brain trying different escapes of quotes and still the $? returns a 1 as long as there are quotes inside the $cmd variable. How do I format the $cmd using quotes to return a 0? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: That's because the single quotes are *part* of argument; they aren't removed after `$cmd` is expanded.

Comment: It's not my code, I have to manipulate the commands to work in the code as written. I tried exporting the cmd variable manually and running it on the command line. I was able to get it to work with '\'Hello\'', but it still wouldn't work in the script.

Comment: Then you have a bug to report.

Comment: @M.Linn, what's the interpreter? If it's bash, I'd suggest putting your code inside an exported function.

Answer (score 3):

The safest option is to use an array:

```
cmd=(egrep -i 'Hello' /home/me/foo.txt)
if (( ${#cmd[@]} > 0 ))
then
    "${cmd[@]}"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "YAY"
    else
        echo "BOO"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: chepner's comment above with the link said to do the same thing. Thank you for putting the code snippet, it definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to export code that uses quotes for use by code that someone else wrote (and which you can't change), a surefire way to do it (so long as that interpreter is bash) is with an exported function:

```
myCmd() { egrep -i 'Hello' /home/me/foo.txt; }
cmd=myCmd

export -f myCmd; export cmd
```

Thereafter, `$cmd` will call `myCmd`, which will call `egrep -i 'Hello' /home/me/foo.txt`.

---

The place where this is important is that if your `Hello` is actually coming from a source that you don't trust. Using string substitution to put that untrusted string into some code would be dangerous -- but if you export it in an environment variable, you can refer to that environment variable safely:

```
# Assume this is in our environment, and came from an untrusted source
stringToSearchFor=$'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''

myCmd() { egrep -i "$stringToSearchFor" /home/me/foo.txt; }

export -f myCmd
export stringToSearchFor
```

whereas it would be **extremely unsafe** to do, say:

```
# DO NOT DO THIS: WILL DELETE YOUR HOME DIRECTORY IF EVAL'D (w/ above malicious sample)
cmd="grep '${stringToSearchFor}' /home/me/foo.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `eval $cmd` in this case.   Eval executes the command as if it were typed on the shell, and returns the exit status of what you ran.

```
if [ -n "$cmd" ]
then
    eval "$cmd"
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "YAY"
    else
        echo "BOO"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: That works, thank you. I will ask the developer if I can change the code to do that. In the mean time is there a way to force the variable to expand the quotes?

Comment: I wouldn't say "want to use" -- this is a fix, but a risky one from a security perspective (as it prevents any mechanism for maintaining the division between code and data).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that is a good thought. I never thought of it from a security perspective. Thanks for that.

Comment: @M.Linn It's not just a security issue; there are lots of ways to get unexpected/unwanted/bizarre results from `eval` without any malicious intent. If it's at all possible, either the array or function approaches are much safer ways to do things.

Comment: @M.Linn, ...this is a kind of error that tends to be seen as a real vulnerability in the wild -- one particular product's admin web UI that let users search logs comes to mind, having been written in a way that was equivalent to `eval`, so by putting `'$(some command here)'` in the string to search for, someone coming from the web UI could run arbitrary commands even if they were only supposed to be allowed to read logs.

Comment: Apparently I started a discussion...   I should point out that if someone can modify `$cmd` to insert malware code, they could also modify an array, or even a function to do an `rm -rf /`.  The vulnerability with `eval` is that if the string passed is derived from a substring, and an untrusted party can manipulate any part of the substring, they could do pretty much whatever they want.  (I had assumed that since OP was running `$cmd` in the first place, it was considered safe).

Comment: @HardcoreHenry, see my answer for discussion around the case where `cmd` itself is coming from trusted software (since it's the OP here providing it), but its *parameters* are not. Using string substitution to generate content to evaluate is inherently risky; moving data out-of-band from code (as my putting only a fixed string in `$cmd` and referring from there to a variable passed out-of-band) is the safe practice.